# Do I have to log in my google webmail every time when I am about to send mail via php from my account ? (swiftmail/phpmailer + google app)

Tags: php, smtp, gmail, swiftmailer

I have build up a mailer bot with php swiftmailer , which can send mails via my google app account, however it only works after I log in my google account on gmail manually, I might be able to send mails via php for few days.

And later the swiftmailer starts return false with some authorization error , I have to log in manually again to make it works.

I don't have large among of mail to send (less 30 or 50 mails per day), not sure if google take me as spamming

So is there any method to send google mail automatically without log in gmail account , or maybe I have to log in google account with php whenever I trying to send mail?

Answer (score 0):

I'm having issues with Google - do you have Google 2-Step verification setup, if so you may require some Application-specific passwords?